# Export and restore a private browsing session in Firefox

Tags: macos, firefox

I mostly use my browser (FF 80, macOS) in private mode. I'm happy with not having history but every time my browser has to shut down (eg browser or OS updates) I lose all my open tabs. I end up manually copying my tabs one by one to a non-private window, so that I can restore them all after reboot.

Is there any more efficient way to grab the URL from every open tab in a private window, store them, and then later re-open each one in a new tab in another private window? I don't care about losing page state.

(Yes, I know I could just use non-private windows like a normal person...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of `Private  browsing` is that once the tab is closed there is no log/history for it.. and you are trying to go against that idea.

One way to do this is to use a Extension like [Tab Session Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-session-manager/) or similar

Comment: I'm aware of that. I'm not trying to get the browser to store the session, just to extract a list of urls and reload them later. That extension works for me - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can bookmark all open tabs (ctrl+shift+D, or go to the bookmark menu) in a folder and them later open all bookmarks in that folder